# Does Azure Isolated App Service Plan provides dedicated (not shared) hardware?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I know that Azure Isolated App Service Plan provide several benefits like:

- Network level isolation
- More worker units
- Better performance

but i wonder if the isolation is also on the hardware level or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Azure **App Service Environment version 3** (**ASEv3**), you can deploy it on a dedicated host group. Host group deployments are not zone redundant for ASEv3.

**Azure Dedicated Host** is a service that provides **physical servers** - able to host one or more virtual machines - dedicated to one Azure subscription. Dedicated hosts are the same physical servers used in our data centers, provided as a resource. You can provision dedicated hosts within a region, availability zone, and fault domain. Then, you can place VMs directly into your provisioned hosts, in whatever configuration best meets your needs.

This is NOT available with **ASEv2**.

#### Reference:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/overview
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dedicated-hosts

Comment: I found this "The ASE is normally deployed on VMs that are provisioned on a multi-tenant hypervisor. If you need to deploy on dedicated systems, including the hardware, you can provision your ASE onto dedicated hosts"